Finiteness of Krull dimension of commutative Noetherian ring for which maximal length of regular sequence in maximal ideals have a uniform upper bound
$\DeclareMathOperator\grade{grade}$Let $R$ be a commutative Noetherian ring. For an ideal $I$ of $R$, let $\grade(I,R)$ be the maximal length of an $R$-regular sequence in $I$.
My question is: If $\sup\{\grade(\mathfrak m, R)\mid \mathfrak m \in \operatorname{MaxSpec}(R)\}$ is finite, then does $R$ have finite Krull dimension?

I believe we can just modify Nagata's counterexample (see for example Exercise 9.6 in Eisenbud's book) as follows. Let $k$ be a field, and $R_n$ be the ring $k[x_{n,1},\dots,x_{n,r_n}]/I_n$ where $I_n$ is chosen so that $R_n$ is an integral domain with Krull dimension $n$ and depth bounded, say by $d$ (there are many ways to do this). Let $R$ be the $k$-algebra generated by all the variables in all the $R_n$ modulo the ideal generated by all the relations in all the $I_n$. Let $\mathfrak{p}_n$ be the ideal generated by $x_{n,1},\dots,x_{n,r_n}$. Let $U$ be the complement in $R$ of the union of the $\mathfrak{p}_n$, and let $S=R[U^{-1}]$. Then $S$ has infinite Krull dimension, is Noetherian, and the maximal ideals $\mathfrak{m}_n$ correspond to the $\mathfrak{p}_n$. The grade of $(\mathfrak{m}_n,S)$ is bounded by $d$.
